# where is UIKIT_DEFINE_AS_PROPERTIES defined?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've found that there is a `UIKIT_DEFINE_AS_PROPERTIES` macro in a lot of places in system's headers like this:

```
#if UIKIT_DEFINE_AS_PROPERTIES
@property(class, nonatomic, readonly) UIDevice *currentDevice;
#else
+ (UIDevice *)currentDevice;
#endif
```

But I cannot find the value of it.

what's the use for `UIKIT_DEFINE_AS_PROPERTIES` and where is it defined?

It is for swift?

Answer (score 1):

`UIKIT_DEFINE_AS_PROPERTIES` is defined in `<UIKit/UIKitDefines.h>` as

```
#if (!defined(SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA) || (defined(SWIFT_SDK_OVERLAY_UIKIT_EPOCH) && SWIFT_SDK_OVERLAY_UIKIT_EPOCH >= 1))
    #define UIKIT_DEFINE_AS_PROPERTIES 1
#else
    #define UIKIT_DEFINE_AS_PROPERTIES 0
#endif
```

The `SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA` and `SWIFT_SDK_OVERLAY_UIKIT_EPOCH`  macros
control how Objective-C code is imported into Swift, compare [ClangImporter.cpp](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/lib/ClangImporter/ClangImporter.cpp).